# how can I add users/numbers to asterisk from php?

Tags: php, python, asterisk

How can I go about adding users/number, changing things from PHP(or python) on an asterisk server?

ps. also are there any better ways to get the current asterisk settings, users, numbers other than scraping the config files?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ASterisk-gui](http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk-gui/releases/asterisk-gui-2.0.4.tar.gz) for this. It does exactly what you need

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I never worked with asterisk. Just some links to look into:

- http://www.straw-dogs.co.uk/asterisk-api-php/
- [Asterisk manager Examples](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Examples)

Comment: Thanks. I will check those out.